# How can i call functions from c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've developed an augmented reality project. But i've a problem. There is a video player script which can play to Video. I'd like to add addition button. So, I created another script for this but i could'nt establish connect between both script. I mean, I'd like to add button that can run play function from VideoPlayBackBehaviour.cs

> VideoHelper.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the VideoPlayerHelper object
/// </summary>
public bool Init()
{
    return videoPlayerInit();
}


/// <summary>
/// Deinitializes the VideoPlayerHelper object
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool Deinit()
{
    return videoPlayerDeinit();
}


/// <summary>
/// Loads a local or remote movie file
/// </summary>
public bool Load(string filename, MediaType requestedType, bool playOnTextureImmediately, float seekPosition)
{
    SetFilename(filename);
    return videoPlayerLoad(mFilename, (int) requestedType, playOnTextureImmediately, seekPosition);
}


/// <summary>
/// Unloads the currently loaded movie
/// After this is called a new load() has to be invoked
/// </summary>
public bool Unload()
{
    return videoPlayerUnload();
}


/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the movie can be played on a texture
/// </summary>
public bool IsPlayableOnTexture()
{
    return videoPlayerIsPlayableOnTexture();
}


/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the movie can be played fullscreen
/// </summary>
public bool IsPlayableFullscreen()
{
    return videoPlayerIsPlayableFullscreen();
}


/// <summary>
/// Set the native texture object that the video frames will be copied to
/// </summary>
public bool SetVideoTextureID(int textureID)
{
    return videoPlayerSetVideoTextureID(textureID);
}


/// <summary>
/// Return the current status of the movie such as Playing, Paused or Not Ready
/// </summary>
public MediaState GetStatus()
{
    return (MediaState) videoPlayerGetStatus();
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns the width of the video frame
/// </summary>
public int GetVideoWidth()
{
    return videoPlayerGetVideoWidth();
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns the height of the video frame
/// </summary>
public int GetVideoHeight()
{
    return videoPlayerGetVideoHeight();
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns the length of the current movie
/// </summary>
public float GetLength()
{
    return videoPlayerGetLength();
}


/// <summary>
/// Request a movie to be played either full screen or on texture and at a given position
/// </summary>
public bool Play(bool fullScreen, float seekPosition)
{
    // On Android we use Unity's built-in full screen movie player

    // On iOS we overlay a native full screen player as a new subview of the main window
    // (note that the Unity engine is not paused in this case)

    if (fullScreen && (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android))
    {
        if (mFilename == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(mFullScreenFilename, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return videoPlayerPlay(fullScreen, seekPosition);
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Pauses the current movie being played
/// </summary>
public bool Pause()
{
    return videoPlayerPause();
}


/// <summary>
/// Stops the current movie being played
/// </summary>
public bool Stop()
{
    return videoPlayerStop();
}


/// <summary>
/// Tells the VideoPlayerHelper to update the data from the video feed
/// </summary>
public MediaState UpdateVideoData()
{
    return (MediaState) videoPlayerUpdateVideoData();
}


/// <summary>
/// Moves the movie to the requested seek position
/// </summary>
public bool SeekTo(float position)
{
    return videoPlayerSeekTo(position);
}


/// <summary>
/// Gets the current seek position
/// </summary>
public float GetCurrentPosition()
{
    return videoPlayerGetCurrentPosition();
}


/// <summary>
/// Sets the volume of the movie to the desired value
/// </summary>
public bool SetVolume(float value)
{
    return videoPlayerSetVolume(value);
}


/// <summary>
/// Gets the buffering percentage in case the movie is loaded from network
/// Note this is not supported on iOS
/// </summary>
public int GetCurrentBufferingPercentage()
{
    return videoPlayerGetCurrentBufferingPercentage();
}


/// <summary>
/// Allows native player to do appropriate on pause cleanup
/// </summary>
public void OnPause()
{
    videoPlayerOnPause();
}
```

> PlayBackBehavior.cs

```
private VideoPlayerHelper mVideoPlayer = null;
private bool mIsInited = false;
private bool mIsPrepared = false;

private Texture2D mVideoTexture = null;

[SerializeField]
[HideInInspector]
private Texture mKeyframeTexture = null;

private VideoPlayerHelper.MediaType mMediaType =
        VideoPlayerHelper.MediaType.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;

private VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState mCurrentState =
        VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY;

private float mSeekPosition = 0.0f;

private bool isPlayableOnTexture;

private GameObject mIconPlane = null;
private bool mIconPlaneActive = false;

#endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



#region PROPERTIES

/// <summary>
/// Returns the video player
/// </summary>
public VideoPlayerHelper VideoPlayer
{
    get { return mVideoPlayer; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the current playback state
/// </summary>
public VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState CurrentState
{
    get { return mCurrentState; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Type of playback (on-texture only, fullscreen only, or both)
/// </summary>
public VideoPlayerHelper.MediaType MediaType
{
    get { return mMediaType; }
    set { mMediaType = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Texture displayed before video playback begins
/// </summary>
public Texture KeyframeTexture
{
    get { return mKeyframeTexture; }
    set { mKeyframeTexture = value; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns whether the video should automatically start
/// </summary>
public bool AutoPlay
{
    get { return m_autoPlay; }
}

#endregion // PROPERTIES



#region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

void Start()
{
    // Find the icon plane (child of this object)
    mIconPlane = transform.Find("Icon").gameObject;

    // A filename or url must be set in the inspector
    if (m_path == null || m_path.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Please set a video url in the Inspector");
        HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR);
        mCurrentState = VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR;
        this.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set the current state to Not Ready
        HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY);
        mCurrentState = VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY;
    }
    // Create the video player and set the filename
    mVideoPlayer = new VideoPlayerHelper();
    mVideoPlayer.SetFilename(m_path);

    // Flip the plane as the video texture is mirrored on the horizontal
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1 * Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x),
            transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);

    // Scale the icon
    ScaleIcon();
}

void OnRenderObject()
{
    if (!mIsInited)
    {
        // Initialize the video player
        if (mVideoPlayer.Init() == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not initialize video player");
            HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR);
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        // Initialize the video texture
        InitVideoTexture();

        // Load the video
        if (mVideoPlayer.Load(m_path, mMediaType, false, 0) == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not load video '" + m_path + "' for media type " + mMediaType);
            HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR);
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        // Successfully initialized
        mIsInited = true;
    }
    else if (!mIsPrepared)
    {
        // Get the video player status
        VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState state = mVideoPlayer.GetStatus();

        if (state == VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR)
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not load video '" + m_path + "' for media type " + mMediaType);
            HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.ERROR);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
        else if (state < VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY)
        {
            // Video player is ready

            // Can we play this video on a texture?
            isPlayableOnTexture = mVideoPlayer.IsPlayableOnTexture();

            if (isPlayableOnTexture)
            {
                // Pass the video texture id to the video player
                int nativeTextureID = mVideoTexture.GetNativeTextureID();
                mVideoPlayer.SetVideoTextureID(nativeTextureID);

                // Get the video width and height
                int videoWidth = mVideoPlayer.GetVideoWidth();
                int videoHeight = mVideoPlayer.GetVideoHeight();

                if (videoWidth > 0 && videoHeight > 0)
                {
                    // Scale the video plane to match the video aspect ratio
                    float aspect = videoHeight / (float) videoWidth;

                    // Flip the plane as the video texture is mirrored on the horizontal
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f * aspect);
                }

                // Seek ahead if necessary
                if (mSeekPosition > 0)
                {
                    mVideoPlayer.SeekTo(mSeekPosition);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the state change
                state = mVideoPlayer.GetStatus();
                HandleStateChange(state);
                mCurrentState = state;
            }

            // Scale the icon
            ScaleIcon();

            // Video is prepared, ready for playback
            mIsPrepared = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (isPlayableOnTexture)
        {
            // Update the video texture with the latest video frame
            VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState state = mVideoPlayer.UpdateVideoData();

            // Check for playback state change
            if (state != mCurrentState)
            {
                HandleStateChange(state);
                mCurrentState = state;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the current status
            VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState state = mVideoPlayer.GetStatus();

            // Check for playback state change
            if (state != mCurrentState)
            {
                HandleStateChange(state);
                mCurrentState = state;
            }
        }
    }

    CheckIconPlaneVisibility();
}


void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
{
    if (!mIsInited)
        return;

    if (pause)
    {
        // Handle pause event natively
        mVideoPlayer.OnPause();

        // Store the playback position for later
        mSeekPosition = mVideoPlayer.GetCurrentPosition();

        // Deinit the video
        mVideoPlayer.Deinit();

        // Reset initialization parameters
        mIsInited = false;
        mIsPrepared = false;

        // Set the current state to Not Ready
        HandleStateChange(VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY);
        mCurrentState = VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.NOT_READY;
    }
}


void OnDestroy()
{
    // Deinit the video
    mVideoPlayer.Deinit();
}
```

> ButtonScript, Also I tried this, but its not working.

```
    void OnMouseDown(){

VideoPlayerHelper  otherScript = GetComponent<VideoPlayerHelper>();

        otherScript.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try googling? if not http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

Comment: I know this method. But i couldn't integrate to play,stop functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know whats is the problem, if you only want to access to a script from other.

Just create a variable with the type of the script :

```
MyScript.cs   
then:

private MyScript script;    
script = GetComponent<MyScript>();
```

In the variable script now you have an instance of MyScript and all the methods. This is going to work only if you have attached all the scripts to the same GameObject.
If you have your script attached to other game object then you need to use:

```
private MyScript otherScript;
anotherScript = otherGameObject.GetComponent<MyScript>();
```

where otherGameObject is the reference to the gameObject where you have the script that you are looking for. You also can assign directly from the editor, your script to your variable (the variable need to be public), just drag and drop the script.

You should try to explain better your cuestion and don't put all the code if is not neccesary. Only the exactly problem. Is hard to check all the code.
  If you have more troubles check this:

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/getcomponent

Comment: Hey, I didn't know this was possible. So let's say for BScript to access AScript through your method, would the AScript have to be in the assets folder? Or something else?

Comment: All your scripts need to be on the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions for you. And these will defintely work, but you HAVE to modify your code according to the solutions:

- Place the button as a child of the Video element in Unity.
- Or, while calling the playBackBehaviour.cs make sure you include a
  global variable for the video element, so that you can attach the
  video that needs to be played directly to the button through the
  Inspector Panel.